# Is there a way to import a .txt file into a workbook from another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a workbook A that create a `.txt`file and i was wondering if there's a way to import that `.txt`file to workbook B? I need to import the `.txt`file into workbook B because the workbook B have a sheet that contain a table that need to be fill with the data in the `.txt`file.

So is it possible to do so while working in workbook A?

so all from workbook A:   WB A = `.txt' -> WB B

Comment: You can open a TXT file as a `TextStream`, read its contents into an array line by line, and do with that array whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your `.txt` table is formatted, change `semicolon:=true` to another delimiter.

```
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Insert path here, DataType:=xlDelimited, local:=True, semicolon:=True

        'Code to copy the contents of the .txt file to your table

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```